# Neumann series expansion for $\sinh(x)$

Tags: calculus

I been Calculate the following Series
$$\sinh ^2(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } J_{2 n+1}(x) \cosh \left((2 n+1) \sinh ^{-1}(2)\right)$$
but the Coefficient of the series Wolfram gives
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sinh ^2(x) J_{2 n+1}(x)}{x} \, dx=-\frac{4 \left(\sqrt{5}-2\right) e^{-2 i \pi  n} \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right)^{-2 n}-4 \left(\sqrt{5}-2\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right)^{-2 n}+8}{16 (2 n+1)}$$
that it seem not correct

What is the wrong part??